# ggplot2: independent axes for grid facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have xy data on a grid with some categorical variables. Here is some dummy data.

```
fn <- function(x,group,type) {
  y <- expand.grid(x=seq(1,x),y=seq(1,x))
  y$group <- group
  y$type <- type
  return(y)
}

dfr <- rbind(
  fn(5,"a","1"),
  fn(5,"b","1"),
  fn(20,"c","1"),
  fn(10,"a","2"),
  fn(50,"c","2")
)

head(dfr)

  x y group type
1 1 1     a    1
2 2 1     a    1
3 3 1     a    1
4 4 1     a    1
5 5 1     a    1
6 1 2     a    1
```

I need them on a grid layout due to the grouping variables.

**Default grid**

Good: Keeps grid layout, Gaps between points fixed, aspect ratio fixed

Bad: Data does not fill facet

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(group~type)+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

[image]

**Grid free scales**

Good: Keeps grid layout, aspect ratio fixed.

Bad: Data does not fill facet, Gaps between points differ

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(group~type,scales="free")+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

[image]

**Grid free scales + free space**

Good: Keeps grid layout, Gaps between points fixed

Bad: Data does not fill facet, Aspect ratio cannot be set

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(group~type,scales="free",space="free")
```

[image]

**Wrap free scales**

Good: Data fills facet, aspect ratio fixed

Bad: Loses grid layout, gap between points not equal

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(group~type,scales="free")+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

[image]

I would like all of these combined.

- Keeps grid layout
- Gaps between points fixed
- Aspect ratio fixed
- Data fills the facet (ie; variable size facets)

I think this is only possible using grid layout with independent axes. Is there some option I am missing or do I have to build this manually?

**Update: 1**
Expected end result.

[image]

**Update 2:**
I think to be able to achieve what I want, the facets need to have free scales, independent axes, fixed aspect ratio and variable sized facets/free space. The first three together are possible using **gghx**.

```
library(gghx)
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid2(group~type,scales="free",independent="all")+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

[image]

Comment: i don't see how it is possible to meet all of these conditions.  if you want the points to be equal distances apart but still fill the space then either the sizes of the plots must be different?

Comment: Yes, the plots need to be different sizes.

Comment: `ggh4x` and `lemon` are two packages that offer some related functions but I'm not sure there's anything exactly like you are after.

Comment: I don't think these conditions are mutually consistent except in certain special cases, and it's unclear which constraints you want to relax to find a working solution. What if one row has a wide plot and then a narrow plot, but the next row has a narrow plot then a wide one? The narrow plots will both have to be smaller and not filling the facet.

Comment: Data cannot fill the facet _and_ have fixed distance between points _and_ be on a grid. The first two conditions would necessitate that each facet has a unique width and height. It's like giving a tiler 9 tiles which are different sizes and shapes then insisting that they be put in a regular grid on the floor without leaving gaps. As @JonSpring says, it might be possible under special circumstances, but the general case is geometrically impossible in this universe.

Comment: I have added the expected end result to show that it is possible. I am sure it is doable by manually tinkering around with patchwork or something. But, I was curious if there was some nifty trick using modifying grobs dimensions for example in the ggplot object.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, perhaps it would be easier to modify the data. For example; recentering coordinates within each facet to mid point of the range for each facet grid row/column and then going with option 1 or 3. Forgot to mention that the actual xy coordinate values do not matter. What matters is the relative distances between the points and aspect ratio.